# A very basic problem with my simple_form usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my form code.

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f|%>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

And this is the error I get  :

compile error
/home/shreyas/apps/vaccidate/app/views/users/_form.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected ')'
... simple_form_for @user do |f|).to_s); @output_buffer.concat
                              ^
/home/shreyas/apps/vaccidate/app/views/users/_form.html.erb:9: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting ')'
/home/shreyas/apps/vaccidate/app/views/users/_form.html.erb:11: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting ')'

What am i supposed to do ?
Thanks !

Comment: Hi What is "simple_form_for"? Maybe it should be "form_for"?

Comment: simple_form is a gem for creating forms. Similar to formtastic, but lightweight compared to formtastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form tag should be this:

```
<% simple_form_for @user do |f|%>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Note on the first line how I am using `<%`, not `<%=`. In Rails 3 for this plugin it will probably change to `<%=`, but it appears you're not using that version. The reason you're getting that error is because it's trying to output the block before it is complete.

Comment: Looks like it now detects simple_form. But now I get this.  You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.+